# What does this fxml error code mean in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Here is the Error code that I keep getting:

```
 Nov 26, 2019 12:33:25 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
    WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.221
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#handlebuttonAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
    /D:/Eclipse%20Java/Workspace/EmployeeApp1/bin/application/Directory.fxml:83

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at application.Main.showMainView(Main.java:27)
        at application.Main.start(Main.java:20)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application application.Main
```

My professor tells me it might be the naming of my application, I went over it and the naming should be right under application file. This is the file setup for my program:

[image: setup]

and here are the codes that I have been using to try and display this by running my main.java file:

[image: Scenebuilder]

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;



public class Main extends Application {
    @FXML private Stage primaryStage;
    @FXML private BorderPane borderPane;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            this.primaryStage.setTitle("Assignment 5: by ");
            showMainView();

    }

        private void showMainView() throws IOException{
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Directory.fxml"));
            borderPane = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Directory.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<TitledPane text="Assignment 5-Kevin Yuan" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.DirectoryController">
   <content>
      <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="320.0">
        <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
        </opaqueInsets>
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" />
        </padding>
        <center>
            <BorderPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <right>
                    <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                        <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="62.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="245.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="245.0" />
                        </columnConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Name:" textAlignment="CENTER">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Company:" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                </font>
                            </Label>
                            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="Extension:" textAlignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                </font>
                            </Label>
                            <TextField fx:id="txtFldName" disable="true" promptText="First Last" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                                <GridPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                </GridPane.margin>
                            </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="txtFldCompany" disable="true" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="85.0" onKeyPressed="#btnLoad" promptText="department name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextField fx:id="txtFldExt" disable="true" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="15.0" onKeyPressed="#btnLoad" promptText="Ext. number" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                            <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblCurrRecord" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="25.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="? of ?" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                        <font>
                                            <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="12.0" />
                                        </font>
                                        <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                                        </HBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                              <Button fx:id="btnNavDel" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" disable="true" maxWidth="35.0" minWidth="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#reactToClick" prefWidth="35.0" text="-">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="SansSerif Bold" size="12.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <opaqueInsets>
                                    <Insets left="20.0" />
                                 </opaqueInsets>
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Button>
                                    <Button fx:id="btnNavAdd" Visible="false" alignment="CENTER" disable="true" maxWidth="35.0" minWidth="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#reactToClick" prefWidth="35.0" text="+">
                                        <font>
                                            <Font name="SansSerif Bold" size="12.0" />
                                        </font>
                                        <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                        </HBox.margin>
                                    </Button>
                                </children>
                            </HBox>
                            <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                <children>
                              <Button fx:id="btnNavPrev" alignment="CENTER" disable="true" maxWidth="35.0" minWidth="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#reactToClick" prefWidth="35.0" text="&lt;&lt;">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="SansSerif Bold" size="12.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Button>
                                    <Button fx:id="btnNavNext" alignment="CENTER" disable="true" maxWidth="35.0" minWidth="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#reactToClick" prefWidth="35.0" text="&gt;&gt;">
                                        <font>
                                            <Font name="SansSerif Bold" size="12.0" />
                                        </font>
                                        <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                        </HBox.margin>
                                    </Button>
                                </children>
                            </HBox>
                        </children>
                    </GridPane>
               </right>
            </BorderPane>
        </center>
         <bottom>
            <BorderPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <right>
                    <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                        <children>
                            <Button fx:id="btnLoad" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#reactToClick" text="Load" textAlignment="RIGHT">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Button>
                            <Button fx:id="btnSerialize" alignment="CENTER" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" text="Serialize" textAlignment="RIGHT">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Button>
                        </children>
                    </HBox>
                </right>
                <center>
                    <Label fx:id="lblFilename" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="File: not set" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </bottom>
         <top>
            <Button fx:id="btnExit" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#Save" onMouseReleased="#Exit" prefWidth="92.0" style="" text="Save and Exit" textAlignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
                <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                </font>
                <BorderPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" top="5.0" />
                </BorderPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </content>
</TitledPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#handlebuttonAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
    /D:/Eclipse%20Java/Workspace/EmployeeApp1/bin/application/Directory.fxml:83
```

Read the above error message : `either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.`, means that you are calling a method for button press which does not exist. Check the below line of FXML code:

```
<Button fx:id="btnExit" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonAction" onMouseClicked="#Save" onMouseReleased="#Exit" prefWidth="92.0" style="" text="Save and Exit" textAlignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
```

A possible solution :
you can remove this `onAction="#handlebuttonAction"` from your FXML code. (The line i have mentioned above.)

Comment: Thank you it works now! its amazing how i miss that error code line.

Comment: Adding the event handler method to the application class, not to the controller class will do nothing regarding fixing the error. It could also mean that the method is not accessible or it has a parameter type that is not a javafx event (e.g. awt's `ActionEvent`)